# Replacing all regular expression matches except a certain character

Tags: python, regex

I would like to please know how I can replace all regular expressions matches except for a certain chosen character.

I need to clean data. An example of the data is

```
`some-really,dirty.data%#$_.`
```

which I would like to look like

```
some-reallydirtydata_
```

Note the `-` between `some` and `really`. That is my chosen character that I would **not** like to remove.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import re

unclean_string = "some-really,dirty.data%#$_."
clean_string = re.sub('\W', '', unclean_string)

print clean_string
>>>"somereallydirtydata_"
```

I know that `\W` removes all but "0 to 9, a to z, A to Z, and underscore".

I want to know how I can remove all of that, plus a chosen character (such as `-`).

Disclaimer: I apologise in advance for asking such a basic question. I am new to Python and using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
clean_string = re.sub(r'[^\w-]', '', unclean_string)
```

`[^\w]` is the equivalent of `\W`. So, if you add a `-` in there, you will not match it either.

Note: I also rawed the regex string above because it's a good practice to do so. This prevents unexpected behaviour you might have especially during escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Include hyphen with your regex:

```
clean_string = re.sub('[^-\w]', '', unclean_string)
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^-\w]                   any character except: '-', word characters
                           (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
```